# jQuery: find overlapping elements between two result sets

Tags: jquery

If I had two jQuery result sets, say

```
$("#someParent *")
```

and

```
$("#someElement").nextAll()
```

then how could I best get all the elements that occur in *both* result sets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var firstSet = $("#someParent *");
var secondSet = $("#someElement").nextAll();
var elementsInBothSets = firstSet.filter(secondSet);
```